# Remove multiple attributes with jQuery's removeAttr

Tags: jquery

I have the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#listing img')
 .attr('width', 250)
 .removeAttr('height').removeAttr('align').removeAttr('style')
 .wrap('<p />');
});
```

Is there a more efficient way of removing multiple attributes?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Yes :

```
.removeAttr('height align style')
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) :

> as of version 1.7, it can be a space-separated list of attributes.

Comment: how do u do it if its not jquery 1.7+?

Comment: @duckx Update. It makes no sense to use an old version of jQuery. Many bugs have been fixed and jQuery is constantly developed to keep up with browser evolutions.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can remove it in that way:

```
$('#listing img').removeAttr('height align style');
```

you can also add those attributes as follows:

```
$('#listing img').attr({ height: "20", align: left }).css({ color: red, text-align: center });
```