# remove image width/height attributes

Tags: jquery, image

I use the following code to load image

```
$(img).load(function () {
                $(img).addClass("itmImgClass");
            }).attr("src", itemData.begedurl);
```

How can I remove the **width** and **height** attributes from the resulting image markup ?

Comment: use removeAttr() -> http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Comment: Why in first place do you have these attributes set in HTML markup?

Comment: @A.Wolff, if I create the image with jQuery Image object (**new Image()**) I am getting a markup with the **Width** and **Height** attributes

Answer (score 1):

Try the [removeAttr() method](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) from jQuery (since you're already using it).

Example: `$(img).removeAttr('width height');`

Comment: removeAttr work fine with **Chrome** and **FF** but does not work with **IE** (I browse with IE11)

Comment: Really? Can you post documentation to this effect?

Answer (score 0):

For removing multiple attributes , use `.removeAttr()`

**[HERE IS THE WAY HOW TO DO IT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725301/remove-multiple-attributes-with-jquerys-removeattr)**